# PDO insert from one DB to another

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to use PDO to read a SQLite DB and then insert into MYSQL.

The read is working and in the foreach I can echo out the SQLite data BUT when it comes to inserting into the new DB nothing logged and no data inserted at all.

```
    try
    {

    $db = new PDO('sqlite:' . $passedFile);
    $dbup = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=TestDB", "dbuser", "password");

    //select all lines from the sqlite DB
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM TestDB');

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      $dbup->exec("INSERT INTO TestDB ('field1','field2','field3') VALUES ('" . $row['field1'] . "','" . $row['field2'] . "','" .$row['field3'] . "')");   
    }


    // close the database connection
    $db = NULL;
    $dbup = NULL;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: And no exceptions were caught?

Comment: Does TestDB exist in the new database, and do all the required fields exist?

Comment: Yes, that part is all checked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As idea, instead of using `$dbup->exec($mysqlQuery)`
try `$dbup->exec($mysqlQuery) or die(print_r($dbup->errorInfo(), true));`

Comment: Perfect that now shows an error on the insert and I was using an integer in quotes which obviously didn't work!